# Javascript Prototype function and SVG setAttribute(onclick)

Tags: javascript, html, svg, onclick, prototypejs

Trying to use an svg onClick to call a prototype function.

Usually to call a prototype function I would just do this.(functionName) but when I put it into the `.setAttribute(onclick, "this.(functionName)")` it does not recognise the prototype function. Has anyone had any experience in this?

In case the above wasn't clear heres the basic jist of it...

```
function myobject(svgShape) {
    this.svgshape.setAttribute(onclick, 'this.doSomething()');
}
myobject.prototype.doSomething = function() {
    alert("works");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To the right when you were asking your question there was a box entitled **How to Format**. Worth a read, as is [the page linked](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) from the **[?]** just above the question area. It tells you how to format your code correctly, that sort of thing. (I've fixed this one for you.) Since you're new: If you haven't already, strongly recommend reading [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) as StackOverflow isn't the same as the various discussion groups, mailing lists, etc. you may be used to.

Answer (score 3):

Three things that may help:

1) First off, I think you're missing this line from the top of your `myobject` function:

```
this.svgshape = svgshape;
```

I'm assuming that was just an error posting the question and have inserted that below.

2) Normally when you're using Prototype (or any modern library), you don't use strings for callbacks, you use *functions*. Also, you normally assign handlers using the library's wrapper for `addEventListener` / `attachEvent` ([`observe`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/observe/), in Prototype's case) rather than the old DOM0 attribute thing. So:

```
function myobject(svgShape) {
    this.svgshape = svgshape;
    $(this.svgshape).observe('click', this.doSomething); // STILL WRONG, see below
}
myobject.prototype.doSomething = function() {
    alert("works");
}
```

3) But JavaScript doesn't have *methods* (it doesn't really need them), it just has functions, so the above won't ensure that `this` (the *context* of the call) is set correctly. With Prototype you'd use [`bind`](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Function/prototype/bind/) to set the context:

```
function myobject(svgShape) {
    this.svgshape = svgshape;
    $(this.svgshape).observe('click', this.doSomething.bind(this));
}
myobject.prototype.doSomething = function() {
    alert("works");
}
```

(Or you can use your own closure to do it. The advantage of `bind` is that the closure is in a very well-controlled environment and so doesn't close over things you don't want kept around.)

Now, I've never done any SVG programming with Prototype, so if `observe` doesn't work for some reason, you might try directly assigning to the `onclick` reflected property:

```
function myobject(svgShape) {
    this.svgshape = svgshape;
    this.svgshape.onclick = this.doSomething.bind(this);
}
myobject.prototype.doSomething = function() {
    alert("works");
}
```

I'm still using `bind` there so that `this` has the correct value.

These posts from my anemic little blog offer more discussion of the above:

- [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)
- [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)